# Change screen resolution without monitor under Linux?

Tags: linux, xrandr, resolution

I got a GUI program which will be executed along the OS (CentOS 6.6) boots.

The resolution configuration is programmed in the `init` part of the GUI program, my solution right now is get the resolution sets of the monitor using `xrandr` and parse the result and set it to one of the candidates, you can choose one of them in the `Preferences` part of the GUI program later. But `xrandr` won't work if no monitor is plugged in, right?

If I got no monitor plugged into the box, that means I have no idea what the resolution sets one monitor can provide, so now what I want is, if I turn on the computer, and the GUI program will be executed, after plugging a monitor later, I can see the GUI program already loaded in the monitor.

I mean I want the resolution fixed (`1152x864 75.0Hz`, for example) in the GUI program init part using some commands or APIs if no monitor plugged?

Does anyone know anything about the available `commands` or `APIs`?

Answer (score 4):

From the xrandr man page:

> --fb widthxheight    Reconfigures the screen to the specified size. All configured     monitors must fit within this size. When this
>   option is not     provided, xrandr computes the smallest screen size
>   that will     hold the set of configured outputs; this option provides
>   a     way to override that behaviour.

Try below without monitor connected -

> xrandr --fb 1280x800

Comment: Does not work for me

Comment: Worked like charm in Ubuntu-Mate v22.04